# programmatically transmitting data using bluetooth LE android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

Anybody knows how to transmitting data using bluetooth LE in android I am able to discover the devices but how can I setup my device for transmitting data to discovering my device into the another device?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Please be more specific

Answer (score 0):

> You can broadcast a service and characteristic , means you gonna
>   create a Peripheral, Other device (Central ) can scan and connect to
>   it.

[Check the Peripheral code](https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGattPeripheral/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothgattperipheral)

Answer (score 0):

For Bluetooth LE Communication, there should be one Central and one Peripheral application. Normally, your mobile will act as central application and devices like fitbit, wearable devices etc. will act as Peripherals.

You can create central application in Android as per Google tutorial from the below link. 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

This central application read advertising data from nearby peripherals using bluetooth LE API s.

If you are interested in creating a custom GATT service [your own peripheral] then you can refer to below link.

https://github.com/devunwired/accessory-samples/tree/master/BluetoothGattPeripheral/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothgattperipheral